# Sinatra/Active Record postgresql adapter

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, sinatra, adapter

I have a working postgresql database. My database.yml file is using "postgresql" for the adapter. I have the pg gem installed (0.12.2). But trying to run my Sinatra app, Passenger gives me this error message: Please install the postgresql adapter: 'gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter' (Could not find pg (~> 0.11) amongst blah blah blah........

Any ideas on why it can't find my pg gem?

Comment: I tried switching to MySQL, and ended up with the same error for a mysql2 adapter. I have the mysql2 gem installed. I just want to write some Ruby code! I'm about to give up and go back to PHP. This has been nothing but a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had installed rvm and ruby under my user, but used "sudo" to install passenger, so passenger was looking in the wrong place for my gems. Reinstalled without sudo and now it works! Hope this helps someone else.